# What to do with this gap under a bathroom window in a masonry wall?

Tags: bathroom, remodeling, stucco, window-frame

1980 block wall house, bathroom remodel with a window. Was expecting a wooden sill but found a 1" gap between window and top of block wall.  How to refinish this?

Thinking to fill window gap with foam insulation and liquid nail 2 layers of backer board as sill to raise to window bottom. Then my 1/4 " Flexstone pvc type final sheeting glues to that. How would you do it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're planning on demolishing all that tile, right?  What's the outside of the window sill look like?

Comment: Yes, I'm taking it down to studs and putting in backer board after insulating. Outside has a small sill, sloping down, all stucco.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use thin-set to attach the backer board.

Then coat at least the top surface and down the vertical wall at least 3 or 4 inches with a waterproofing agent like Redguard or Aqua Defense.  That would be my insurance if the seam between the wall panel and the sill cover failed.

Comment: Sounds very wise. I was planning on putting redguard over all backer board. Joints and using thinset would allow me to slope the sill downwards just a tad so the water wouldn't pool on the sill. Thanks for that advice.

Comment: Sounds like you got it all figured out.  Good Luck.